# composeWithTracker returns undefined arguments

Tags: meteor, reactjs

This Meteor client code prints `into is undefined` to the console. It is expected to print the value of the `info.description` property passed to the `composeWithTracker(composer)(Info)` at the bottom of the code.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks

```
//--------------- carInfo.jsx ---------------
import React from 'react';

const renderWhenData = ( info ) => {
  console.log( 'info is ' +info); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< undefined
  if ( info ) {
    return <span>{ info.description }</span>;
};

export let Info = ( { info } ) => (
  <p>{ renderWhenData( info ) }</p>
);

//--------------- carClass.jsx ---------------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { Info } from '../ui/carInfo.jsx';

const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('vehicles');
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const cars = Vehicles.findOne({name: 'Jack'});  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< document OK.
    onData(null, { cars });
  }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker(composer)(Info);
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-info'));
```

Comment: You are sending an object with a `cars` property and expect to receive an object with an `info` property.

Comment: @MasterAM I am having hard time getting my head around chaining the method arguments ()(). changing "info" to "cars" inside carInfo.jsx fixed the problem but would like to understand why. isn't the name "info" or whatever, is valid in its own context inside `renderWhenData` and thus independent from the context inside `composer`?

Comment: You should really start by reading more about ES2015. Those are fundamental topics.